# Execute String In Javascript Without Eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I have done it with `eval` but I read that [eval is evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/). So I am curious: how do I write this without `eval()`?. I already tried some sample but it didn't work. Is it possible to do this without `eval` or is `eval` the only way?

```
$(".test").each(function(){
    var xyz = "";
    var w = $(this).last().attr("name");
    for(var i=0; i< (w-1);i++){
        var xyz = xyz + ".prev()";
    }
    var x = '$(this).first().parent()' + xyz;
    var y = x + '.find("td.one").attr("rowspan",'+w+');';
    eval(y);    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval()` isn't evil, it's just almost always the wrong tool for the job. For example, your algorithm can be implemented without messing around with strings at all, so then you wouldn't need to consider `eval()`:

```
$(".test").each(function(){
    var w = $(this).attr("name");
    var el = $(this).parent();
    for(var i=0; i < w-1; i++){
        el = el.prev();
    }
    el.find("td.one").attr("rowspan", w);
});
```

Note also that your use of `.last()` and `.first()` was redundant, because within your `.each()` loop `this` will refer to a single DOM node.